# How to make a memo reminder of date&time in android

Tags: android

Well I am trying to develop a memo or notebook app with a new feature of reminding the users in certain date and time they set.

I used datepicker and timepicker to pick up date and time, and I use alarmmanager to set an alarm to notify the users, but I don't know how to check the date, could anyone help me?

THX

PS, is there any opensource android apps about it? I would like to know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) class to schedule reminders. It allow you to schedule your application to be run at some point in the future. Here's a sample code to get you started:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourMemoService.class);
PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, 0);
AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, Time_To_wake, pending);
```

Comment: But time to wake only allow time, isn't? So how should I set this time to wake to make it possible for the right date?